# React index.js Unknown word

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an index.js file in my root directory but whenever I run `npm start` i get an Unknown word in index.js error.
How do I fix this problem? Looked online but can't seem to get it running. Since there is very little info about this error.

```
//index.js
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App'

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />)
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like you're trying to use ES6 modules type imports. This will only work if in your main index.html you'll import the index.js file as a "module":
`<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>`

Comment: I wonder why you have `css-loader` processing for your `index.js` file. Did you modify the webpack config?

Comment: @qrsngky i didn't edit the webpack config. However, I had to write a web.config to get the React Routing running on Windows IIS.

Comment: It looks like some tests in the webpack config for running css-loader matches your js file name. If you search for `webpack unknown word error` in google, the results are related to `css-loader`.

Comment: @qrsngky yes thanks, just found it. Had an autocompletion mistake. I wanted to import a css file but I autocorrected the index.js in the import statement which resulted in this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the cause of this error. It was due to an autocompletion mistake. I have a global css file where I set up the css variables I use in this project such as font and background colors.

Said file needs to be imported into the css files that want to access given variables.

```
/* How it should look like */
@import url('../../../vars.css');

/* How it's not supposed to look like */
@import url('../../../index.js');
```

I accidentally autocompleted the index.js into the import statement which resulted in the error.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this way

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as ReactDOMClient from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: it results in the same error

Answer (score 0):

You should use `render` method imported from `'react-dom'`

```
// index.js
// import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'

// const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Still throws the same Error. now it marks the import in line 1 as the "Unknown word"

Comment: @Luke_KS try deleting node_modules folder and running npm install or yarn install again.

Comment: I tried that already, but it didn't fix the issue either